# Dynamically populate authorize attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using windows authentication with no roles setup, I simply have some admin names stored in a table that I want to check against in combination with the authorize attribute. I don't have much experience using this, but the only examples I see are hard coded values like below so I'm not sure if this functionality is available or if I'd need to add it.

```
[Authorize(Users = @"domain\user1, domain\user2")]
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Couldn't you achieve this using the [impersonation in an ASP.NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306158)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up adding this myself, very easy to do.

```
public class AuthorizeUser : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        string[] admins = 
        //get user names

        if (admins.Contains(httpContext.User.Identity.Name))
            return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

Then to use just

```
[AuthorizeUser]
```

Comment: I am sorry, I do not fully understand what is the use of this attribute? wouldn't you be simply using the `[Authorize]` attribute by doing this? I mean, the authorize attribute makes sure that some user is logged in, you are just finding out that some user is equal to the same user? which is kind of redundant.

Comment: @Lordbalmon If you read this answer in combination with the question, you'll see that I'm comparing it with a custom list of users. I left out where I'm assigning admins but in my case it's just a custom list of users from a table. In summary, I'm going a step beyond checking if a user is logged in, I'm also checking them against a custom list of admins.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, I did not understand that part either because you could just use the `Authorize(Roles = "Admin,...")`, I guess the user's requirements were just different.

Comment: @Lordbalmon You are correct, had I been using roles I could have achieved the same result without a custom attribute.